# How to use packer.use inside neovim?

Tags: neovim, vimscript-lua

I was switching vimscript to lua in neovim, and I saw packer.nvim is a famous plugin manager for lua. In this README.md file I saw I can use startup function, but it's not required and I can also use packer.use.

So I required my plugin file in init.lua

and then this is the plugins.lua

```
local packer = require('packer')
packer.init {
    disable_commands = true
}
local use = packer.use
packer.reset()

use {
    'wbthomason/packer.nvim'
}
```

after that when I run nvim it is not allowing to use PackerSync

but when I remove disable commands from packer.init, it works fine(if i don't remove packer.init())

but when I remove the function packer.init(), it is not allowing me to use PackerSync

my question is in this below link,wbthomason also used disable_commands = true, and also lvim also used disable_commands, how can it be worked fine?

https://github.com/wbthomason/dotfiles/blob/linux/neovim/.config/nvim/lua/plugins.lua

Comment: A totally unwelcome advice: **do not** switch to Lua unless you either **know Lua well already** or **really want to learn it**. Otherwise, it's just a waste of the time.

Comment: sorry I didn't knew lua that much. but i heard lua faster than vimscript, that's why i switched to this. any suggestion to learn lua?

Comment: Language X cannot be faster than language Y, because languages do not run. What Lua has is JIT/VM. But your script won't be able to get anything from it.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`disable_commands = true` was disabling `PackerInstall`, `PackerSync`, etc., but not the plugin, so I switched to using `packer.sync()` inside `plugins.lua`, and it worked fine.